# Why am I getting a 'Missing Permissions' error when trying to use my ban command in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, command

I was coding a ban command but when I tested it and tried it on my discord server, it didnt work, so I added an extra line of code just to log the error message on the console and it said **DiscordAPIError[50013]: Missing Permissions**, even tho before I added my bot to the server I gave it adminstrator permissions so he can do any thing, but still it made an error and I dont see any error on my code, even with ESlint.

```
const {SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, PermissionFlagsBits, ActionRowBuilder} = require('discord.js');
const chalk = require('chalk');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ban')
        .setDescription('Bans a member')
        .addMentionableOption(option =>
            option
                .setName('target-user')
                .setDescription('The user you want to ban.')
                .setRequired(true))
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option
                .setName('reason')
                .setDescription("Reason for the user's ban."))
        .setDMPermission(false  )
        .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.BanMembers),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const targetuser = interaction.options.getMentionable('target-user', true);
        const Reason = interaction.options.getString('reason') ?? 'No reason provided';

        const confirm = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('confirm')
            .setLabel('Yes')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger);
        
        const cancel = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('cancel')
            .setLabel('No')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary);

        const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(confirm, cancel);
        
        const response = await interaction.reply({
            content: `Are you sure you want to ban this user?`,
            ephemeral: true,
            components: [row],
        });

        try {
            const confirmation = await response.awaitMessageComponent({time: 60_000, ComponentType: 2});

            if (confirmation.customId === 'confirm') {
                const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setTitle('User Banned!')
                    .setDescription(`User ${targetuser} has been banned by ${interaction.user}.`)
                    .addFields(
                        {name: 'Reason', value: Reason},
                    )
                    .setFooter({text: 'craig tucker'})
                    .setTimestamp();
                await interaction.guild.members.ban(targetuser, {reason: Reason});
                await interaction.channel.send({embeds: [embed]});
                await interaction.editReply({content: `User ${targetuser} banned successfully.`, components: [],});
            }
        } catch (error) {
            await interaction.editReply({
                content: "Confirmation not received within 1 minute, cancelling",
                components: [],
            });
            console.log(chalk.red(error));
        }
    },
};
```

the error happens after I clicked on the button that confirmed the ban, so I tried modifying the interactionCreate event on his event file:

```
const {Events} = require("discord.js");
const chalk = require('chalk');

module.exports = {
    name: Events.InteractionCreate,
    async execute(interaction) {
        if (interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {
            const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

            if (!command) {
                console.log(chalk.red(`command ${interaction.commandName} does not exist.`));
                return;
            }

            try {
                await command.execute(interaction);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(chalk.red(`error while trying execute "${interaction.commandName}" (command): ${error}`));
            }
        }  
    },
};
```

but it was perfectly fine, according to the discord.js guide (due to interaction with buttons and slash commands being the same), then I checked my index.js file and tried modifying my client intents variable by adding `GatewayIntentBits.AutoModerationExecution,` but still, error at the console.

Comment: Is the person you're trying to ban at or above the permission level of the bot?

Comment: No, i was trying to ban my friend (which was lower than the permission level of the bot) but when i clicked the button to confirm the ban it simply didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons this error can be thrown:

- The bot is trying to ban itself
- The bot is trying to ban the guild owner
- The bot is the guild owner
- The bots highest role is not higher than the targets highest role
- The bot doesn't have permissions to ban guild members.

[source 1](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/stable/src/structures/GuildMember.js#L293)
[source 2](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/stable/src/structures/GuildMember.js#L271)